# dynamically fill dropdown with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

i found this code

```
$("#choice1").change(function() {
$("#choice2").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#choice1").val());
});
```

from here https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/

and i want to change it a little bit in order to fill three dropdown lists instead of two. So, for example, when someone chooses first choice the second choice fills up with "something" and this "something" i want to parse it in another_getter.php file in order to fill up the third dropdown list with "something else".
My actualy problem is how to call these jquery functions and i was thinking something like,

```
$("#choice1").change(function() {
$("#choice2").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#choice1").val());
$("#choice3").load("getter2.php?choice2=" + $("#choice2").val());
});
```

but it doesn't work. Can someoene tell me how should i properly call these functions?
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jq method is async. You should load content to other dropdown once content has been loaded, setting logic in complete callback:

```
$("#choice1").change(function() {
  $("#choice2").load("getter.php?choice=" + $(this).val(), function() {
    $("#choice3").load("getter2.php?choice2=" + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the sequence of your problem, I think is this what you are looking for:

```
$("#choice1").change(function() {
    $("#choice2").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#choice1").val());
});

$("#choice2").change(function() {
    $("#choice3").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#choice2").val());
});

$("#choice3").change(function() {
   // Do stuff
});
```